# SQL запрос, обновление записей

Tags: jdbc, java, sql

Привет хэш-код, привела меня к вам большая ошибка, которую я при недостатке опыта решить не могу ((

SQL запрос обновления записи таблицы записан так:

```
String sqlReqest = "UPDATE "+strTableName+" SET Qestion='"+strQestoinText+"' WHERE Qestion='"+strRedactRecordQestion+"'";
```

Работает нормально, но проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно обновить не одно значение из записи, а все. К обновлению я добавил еще одно значение, и получился такой запрос:

```
String sqlReqest = "UPDATE "+strTableName+" SET Qestion='"+strQestoinText+"' , FirstAnswer='"+strFirstAnswer+"' WHERE Qestion='"+strRedactRecoedQestion+"'";
```

Возвращает ошибку: слишком мало параметров. Требуется 1 запрос

```
String sqlReqest = "UPDATE "+strTableName+" SET Qestion='"+strQestoinText+"' AND FirstAnswer='"+strFirstAnswer+"' WHERE Qestion='"+strRedactRecoedQestion+"'";
```

Возвращает ту самую ошибку. Есть какой-то выход, чтобы не писать отдельный запрос для каждого поля записи?

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: ты бы попробовал написать этот запрос простым sql. Посмотрел бы, что не так... =) 

> Это может быть, если имя поле написали
> не так или вообще такого поля нет!

Answer (score 5):

```
String sqlReqest = "UPDATE "+strTableName+" SET Qestion='"+strQestoinText+"' AND FirstAnswer='"+strFirstAnswer+"' WHERE Qestion='"+strRedactRecoedQestion+"'";
```

Нет. Смотрите референс по sql - 
`UPDATE table SET param1=value1,param2=value2 WHERE paramN=someValue`.
Если вы хотите Обновить несколько строк, то вам нужно использовать условия после директивы WHERE - То есть `Condition1 OR (Condition2 AND Conditio3)` (Это например)
Зрите в корень - в sql, ну т.е. [сюда](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)